# How to spool cells to different files?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

Is it possible to spool the content of the different rows of a table to different files?

The Number of rows of my table is not fixed and it has these columns:
ID, NAME, CONTENT_TO_SPOOL

I would like to create an output file per row, spooling the CONTENT_TO_SPOOL to files called NAME.txt

This is some pseudo-code of what I want to achieve:

```
FOR row IN SELECT * FROM MyTABLE LOOP
   spool row.NAME.txt
       dbms_output.put_line(row.CONTENT_TO_SPOOL);
   spool OFF
END LOOP;
```

I realize that `SPOOL` is part of SQL PLUS while the `FOR LOOP` is a PL/SQL construct, so my pseudo code doesn't work.
I can not write to the server, therefore `UTL_FILE` is out of the question.

Is there a way I could loop through the rows in SQL PLUS and use `SPOOL` to save the content to different files?

Comment: You could format your output as a shell script, directing each cell into a different file, and then run the shell script.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're trying to do this with SQL*Plus rather than writing a small application/ script in whatever language you'd prefer?  It's easy enough to write a small Java/ C#/ C++/ perl/ python/ shell script that runs on the client, connects to the database, and generates files on the client.  Theoretically, I suppose you could write a SQL*Plus script that dynamically built another SQL*Plus script that it then executed.  But that would seem rather more involved than would seem appropriate.

Comment: @JustinCave - This is not for me to run, other users have limitations as to what they can run.They however have access and understanding of SQL, so if they needed to they can edit the set of scripts I am working on. This is just a small portion. And you are totally right, this is way easier on other languages, but they don't know those.

Comment: @Politank-Z - I think you mean doing something similar to what Mina and TenG suggested, right? I was trying to do something like that, but got really stuck.

Comment: I was thinking in terms of outputting a bash script, but their answers are in the same spirit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pseudo code does not make it clear what you want, but here goes ....

This method works by generating a script from the data to re-query the data with embedded spool commands for each distinct NAME.

```
set lines 200
set trimspool on
set head off pages 0
-- may need more set stuff to ensure output is clean
spool run_query.sql
select distinct 'spool ' || name || '.txt' || chr(10) ||
                'select content_to_spol from mytable where name = ''' || name || ''';' || chr(10) ||
                'spool off' cmd
from mytable;
spool off
@run_query.sql
```

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, you answered perfectly though. My case is more complex and I was trying to simplify it so it would make sense. I was doing something similar but I got stuck, finally I got something  similar to you have, but yours is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of one way of doing this is in SQL Plus. Not nice,  but it works       :    1. create script.sql with following content

```
set serveroutput on
spool step1.log
declare
begin
  for rec in (select rownum as id, col_a, col_b from mytable)
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('spool file_'||rec.id||'.log');
    dbms_output.put_line('select '''||rec.col_a|| ''' as vchar_col , '||rec.col_b|| ' as num_col from dual;');
    dbms_output.put_line('spool off');
end loop;
end;
/
spool off
```

2. `@script.sql;`

Now you have file step1.log with following content:

spool file_1.log
select 'a' as vchar_col , 4 as num_col from dual;
spool off
spool file_2.log
select 'b' as vchar_col , 44 as num_col from dual;
spool off

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

3. Remove the last line (PL/SQL procedure succesfully completed) and execute @step1.log
4. file_1.log and file_2.log, etc... are created, each contains one row of table mytable

Comment: I like your answer and explanation, I only have accepted TenG's because his approach is simpler. Thanks!